# LoginRequiredMixin, How to get and use the redirect_field_name?

Tags: python, django

I don't know whether this is the correct way to use this, if not, please let me know:

I have a view protected with the mixin like this:

```
class ControlPanel_vw(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'controlPanel.html'
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
```

And my login view receiving like this:

```
class Login_vw(FormView):
    form_class = EmailAndPassword_fr
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.next = request.GET.get('next')
        return super(Login_vw, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        formData_d = form.clean()
        email_f = formData_d.get("email")
        password_f = formData_d.get("password")

        print self.next

        return super(Login_vw, self).form_valid(form)
```

When I print self.next in the get method it works good.

I used the "self" before "next" with the intention to can use it from the other function "form_valid", so when the user do login I can send him to his last url.

But when I tried to print the self.next variable just to test, I get:

> 'Login_vw' object has no attribute 'next'

I don't know what I am doing wrong, can you tell me what and why? I don't have clear the use of the self between functions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`form_valid()` is called from the `FormView`s `post()` method, which it runs only when there is POSTed form data.

You are saving `self.next` in the `get()` method which will not be called when there is a POST request - hence the value is not set when you try to access it in `form_valid()`.

You don't need to split this logic between two methods anyway - why not just fetch the `next` GET parameter when you need it?

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    formData_d = form.clean()
    email_f = formData_d.get("email")
    password_f = formData_d.get("password")

    next = self.request.GET.get('next')
    # Do something with next...

    return super(Login_vw, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/
Thanks for you answer

When I do it, I get nothing in the variable, it gave me "none" value.

And when I do the print of self.request.GET I got this:
`<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: I think, when I send the form data, the URL change, so when the form_valid  method is called, there is nothing now in the GET.

Comment: If the URL changes then you will need to find another way to pass that information to the view.

Comment: I mean when the form_valid method is called, I think at that moment the URL must be different, because as you said, this method is called after POST, right?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `get` method and added the `get_context_data` instead:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Login_vw, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['next'] = self.request.GET.get('next')
        return context
```

and then in my tamplate form added this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
```

then within the `form_valid` method retrieve the "`next`" variable like this:

```
next = self.request.POST.get('next')
```

And thats it, in a brief explanation, `get_context_data` receives the next url, send it to the *template form*, and the template form sends it back to the `form_valid` method.